# Location tag error in web.config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, authorization, forms-authentication

I'm trying to set a different authentication and authorization for a page (Master.aspx) in my website. I tried to use location tag, but I get an error.

I have this code in my Web.Config file :

```
   <configuration>
     <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="360"/>
       <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
       </authorization>

     </system.web>

     <location path ="Master.aspx">
       <system.web>
         <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms name ="MasterCookie" timeout="30" loginUrl="Register.aspx" />
         </authentication>
         <authorization>
           <deny users="?"/>
           <allow users="admin"/>
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
     </location>

   </configuration>
```

And I got an error at 17:

```
   Line 15:   <location path ="Master.aspx">
   Line 16:     <system.web>
   Line 17:       <authentication mode="Forms">
   Line 18:         <forms name ="MasterCookie" timeout="30" loginUrl="Register.aspx" />
   Line 19:       </authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in location tag, there shouldn't be any authentication